Flutter Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter
Hello i have this error on my flutter app, how can fix this?
spec file:
name: quote
description: quote

version: 3.2.0+20

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  custom_switch: ^0.0.1
  settings_ui: ^0.4.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
  simple_permissions: any
  location: ^2.5.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.3
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  barcode_scan2: any
  intl: ^0.17.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  pdf: ^3.4.1
  advance_pdf_viewer:
    git: https://github.com/ncdm-stldr/pdf_viewer.git
  data_tables: ^1.0.3
  network_image_to_byte: ^0.0.1
  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.0
  image: ^3.0.1
  line_icons: any
  printing: ^5.7.4
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.3.8
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.0
  back_button_interceptor: ^4.2.4
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.4
  provider: ^4.1.3
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.0
  image_picker: any
  image_cropper: ^1.2.0
  flutter_picker: any
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  file_picker: ^4.3.0
  cross_file: ^0.3.2
  cron: ^0.4.0
  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.2+1
  line_awesome_flutter: ^1.0.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^1.0.2
  animated_theme_switcher: ^1.0.5
  _fe_analyzer_shared: ^34.0.0
  theme_provider: ^0.5.0
  timer_builder: ^2.0.0
  ionicons: any
  dropdown_button2: ^1.0.0
  flutter_custom_tabs: "^0.6.0"
  url_launcher: ^5.4.0
  camera: any

dev_dependencies:
  dart_code_metrics: ^4.8.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.0.1

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/img/icona.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/avatar.png
    - assets/images/addicon.png
    - assets/images/logo.png


  fonts:
    - family: WorkSansSemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-SemiBold.ttf
    - family: WorkSansBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Bold.ttf
    - family: WorkSansMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Medium.ttf

Flutter error:
Xcode's output:
↳
    ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/numberpicker-2.1.2/lib/src/numberpicker.dart:197:66: Error: The getter 'bodyMedium' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
     - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyMedium'.
        final defaultStyle = widget.textStyle ?? themeData.textTheme.bodyMedium;
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/numberpicker-2.1.2/lib/src/numberpicker.dart:199:29: Error: The getter 'headlineSmall' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
     - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'headlineSmall'.
            themeData.textTheme.headlineSmall
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to package /Users/riccardo/Desktop/Progetti/Personali/quoteflutter/ios/...
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPad di Riccardo.


have you tried deleting build folder?

can you please mention your flutter version?

It seems that the package numberpicker that you are using is incompatible with the latest flutter version. I think your only options are to downgrade your flutter version or to not use this package anymore, possibly by forking the code of the package and making fixes in it so it doesn't use deprecated methods anymore

i not use this packages

the error seems to indicate otherwise. Check your pubspec.yaml file. If it's there simply remove it, since you don't seem to be using it. If you don't see it there it might be that another package that you are using is depending on it

i have add pubspec.yaml

it looks like many of the packages you use are not compatible with the latest flutter version,  and for some of them even their latest version doesn't. If you really need those packages it seems the only option is to use an older version of flutter
